# function to display an image doesn't work

Tags: javascript, d3.js, selection

I have the following d3 code:

```
function show_image(source) {
 d3.select("#static-a").append("image").attr("src", source);
}
```

I know that the first part of the selection is correct, and that the source variable is a valid local, relative reference path when the function is being called:

```
show_image("../images/image_netflix.png");
```

Comment: Are you trying to append image to an SVG or DIV?

Comment: static-a is a div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `img` instead of `image`.

```js
d3.select("body")
  .append("button")
  .on("click", function() {
   show_image("http://www.logosdesigners.com/images/img_example.jpg");
  })
  .text("Show Image");

function show_image(source) {
  d3.select("#static-a").selectAll("img").remove(); //Removing existing images
  d3.select("#static-a").append("img").attr("src", source); //Appending new image
}
```

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

#static-a {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid teal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="static-a"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you meant to say this:

```
append("<img>").attr("src", source);
```

or just do this:

```
append($("<img>", {"src":source }));
```

Comment: So with both of those I get 'InvalidCharacterError: String contains an invalid character' and the image doesn't load which means I'm not calling the selection correctly from what I understand?